# How to use the value of a variable as an argument

Tags: python, variables, arguments

I am trying to use the value of a variable, which is a string, as an argument and I keep getting "'Str' not callable' error. I haven't used str as a variable name I can make the code work with `eval`, however, I've read dire warnings about `eval`, so am unsure what to do.  My code is below.

```
from time import sleep
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager


class s33():    

    def __init__(self):

        self.client = Client("", "")
        self.bm = BinanceSocketManager(self.client)



    def process_trade_message(self, message):
        global count, conn_key
        print(count)
        if count >= 10:

            print('closing socket')
            # use either stop_socket or close, or both
            self.bm.stop_socket(conn_key)
            self.bm.close()

            # reset the count
            count = 0

    def go(self, sockb):
        global count, conn_key


        print(sockb['1'])
        sock = 'self.bm.'+sockb['1']
        print(sock)
        count = 0
        conn_key = sock(self.process_trade_message)

        self.bm.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        s = s33()
        socka = {'1':'start_miniticker_socket'}
        s.go(socka)
        sleep(20)
        print('sleeping')
```

I have read people recommend using a dict, So I passed the dict as the arg and tried to extract the string in the function,which is the code below. I tried to extract the string and pass that as an arg to the function. `s.go(socka['1']`, I tried passing the just the variable as an arg, `socka = 'start_miniticker_socket'` and I can get that to work if I use `eval('self.bm'+socka)` I tried the percentage sign with no luck. Not sure how to do this without using eval. I am still fairly new and can't find an alternative answer after several hours of searching that works. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you should also be cautious of the usage of `global`.
It's better to do something like this: `instance = s33(conn_manager)`, then having `count` and `conn_key` as attributes of `conn_manager`

Comment: I mean if `conn` and `conn_key` is shared with other objects, it's better to make them belong to a shared object, and pass that object around using dependency injection.

Comment: something like this a separate class?

Comment: `from binance.client import Client`
`from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager`
`class conn_manager():`
    `def __init__():`
    `client = Client("", "")`
    `bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)`
    `count = x`
    `conn_key = sock(process_trade_message)`
sorry, it rendered badly.

Comment: Thank you for giving me keywords to search for to help me know what I don't know. It dependency injection was something I had no idea existed. Now to learn about that.

Comment: I was able to get around the global variables by nesting my callback inside my calling function. Is this not an optimal solution? If you would like, I can post my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what people meant when suggesting a dict is something like this:

```
class s33():
    # Codes...
    def go(self, func_name):
        global count, conn_key

        print(func_name)
        mapper = {
            'start_miniticker_socket': self.bm.start_miniticker_socket
        }
        # Get self.bm.start_miniticker or None
        sock = mapper.get(func_name)
        print(sock)
        if sock:
            count = 0
            conn_key = sock(self.process_trade_message)

            self.bm.start()
        else:
            pass # Handle when sock is None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        s = s33()
        socka = 'start_miniticker_socket'
        s.go(socka)
        sleep(20)
        print('sleeping')
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you for taking the time to answer